# Hide ngTable td which has data-title

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a ngTable as below.

I wanted to hide the first cell using ng-if based on the role.

When I added ng-if then the content of the td (Radio button) is hidden correctly but the data-title is still visible in the screen

Is it possible to hide the td completely?

```
<table ng-table="tableParam" 
    class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered list-table" id="tableList" 
    fixed-header >
         <tr ng-repeat="valuesList in $data">
             <td ng-if="role=='ADMIN'" data-title="'Select'">
                    <input type="radio" name="selectRadio" ng-model="selectRadio" ng-value="valuesList"  ></input>
             </td>
             <td data-title="'Start Date'">{{valuesList.startDate}}</td>
             <td data-title="'End Date'">{{valuesList.endDate}}</td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: what do you mean by **date-title** still visible? can you elaborate your question?

Comment: @Aravind: I meant that the title is still visible in the screen but the radio button is hidden correctly

Answer (score 1):

Please create class for hide your content

```
<style>
 .hidden {
    display : none
 }
</style>
```

Use below code for your `ng-table`

```html
<table ng-table="tableParam" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered list-table" id="tableList" fixed-header >
         <tr ng-repeat="valuesList in $data">
             <td ng-if="role=='ADMIN'" header-class="(role!='ADMIN') ? 'hidden' : ''" data-title="'Select'">
                    <input type="radio" name="selectRadio" ng-model="selectRadio" ng-value="valuesList"/>
             </td>
             <td data-title="'Start Date'">{{valuesList.startDate}}</td>
             <td data-title="'End Date'">{{valuesList.endDate}}</td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

here i have used condition for hidden class add `if role == 'Admin' than class apply` other-wise working as it as you want

**header-class** will helps you to hide your Header in `ng-table` and `ng-if` condition for your data hide.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-create the problem using the plunkr but unable to re-create the issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xJgzQCXTwBMcS5dptpYN?p=preview

May be there is something wrong in my application somewhere else which I couldn't identify.

I have solved the issue using the below solution: (applied the ng-if to tr or div tag etc instead of td)

```
 <table ng-table="tableParam" 
        class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered list-table" id="tableList" 
        fixed-header >
             <tr ng-if="role=='ADMIN'" ng-repeat="valuesList in $data">
                 <td data-title="'Select'">
                        <input type="radio" name="selectRadio" ng-model="selectRadio" ng-value="valuesList"  ></input>
                 </td>
                 <td data-title="'Start Date'">{{valuesList.startDate}}</td>
                 <td data-title="'End Date'">{{valuesList.endDate}}</td>
             </tr>
             <tr ng-if="role=='NOTADMIN'" ng-repeat="valuesList in $data">
                 <td data-title="'Start Date'">{{valuesList.startDate}}</td>
                 <td data-title="'End Date'">{{valuesList.endDate}}</td>
             </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short you can't. Because the header part was created when the table is inited. However, you can do this:

```
<table ng-table="tableParam" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered list-table" id="tableList" fixed-header>
  <thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="valuesList in $data">
      <th ng-if="role=='ADMIN'">a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="valuesList in $data">
      <td ng-if="role=='ADMIN'">
        <input type="radio" name="selectRadio" ng-model="selectRadio" ng-value="valuesList"></input>
      </td>
      <td>{{valuesList.b}}</td>
      <td>{{valuesList.c}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table ng-table="tableParam" 
    class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered list-table" id="tableList" 
    fixed-header >
         <tr ng-repeat="valuesList in $data">
             <td ng-if="role=='ADMIN'" data-title="'Select'">
                    <input type="radio" name="selectRadio" ng-model="selectRadio" ng-value="valuesList"  ></input>
             </td>
             <td ng-if="role=='ADMIN'" data-title="'Start Date'">{{valuesList.startDate}}</td>
             <td ng-if="role=='ADMIN'" data-title="'End Date'">{{valuesList.endDate}}</td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

This should do the trick. If you don't want to add multiple `ng-if`, then wrap the `<td>` inside a `<tbody>` and apply `ng-if` on the `<tbody>`